# clearcase gui in source code management - change location

Tags: jenkins, clearcase

Clearcase plugin GUI appears in source code management section in Jenkins.

Is there any way to change the location so that this GUI should appear somewhere else? (may be in advanced project options etc).

Which file in CC plugin need to be changed?

I am modifying CC plugin for another function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should be related to the [`ClearCaseSCMDesriptor`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/clearcase-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/clearcase/ClearCaseSCM.java#L92), which [returns an instance](https://github.com/jenkinsci/clearcase-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/clearcase/ClearCaseSCM.java#L252-L266) of [`hudson.scm.SCM`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/scm/SCM.java).

I suspect the "Source code Management" illustrated in the picture below) lists all plugin settings that returns an instance of the `SCM` class.

I don't know if you can easily change that though.

[image: http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/file/n3313107/jenkins_error.jpg]

Comment: But in case if we make a new job (a hello world) and we want to place it in a specified section in Jenkins, how we can do that?

Comment: @Afzal I suspect by implementing that plugin in a way its descriptor extends the right class (deriving from `ExtensionPoint`) corresponding to that section. For "Source Code Management", that class was `hudson.scm.SCM`.